# How do I reset the values in javascript without using .animate, related with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, fade

I'm changing this div's (#logo)attributes like this

```
$('#logo').stop().animate({
left: 150,
height: 78,
marginTop: 45
}
```

After 2 seconds after animation is finished, I make it disappear with .hide('slow'), now while it is hidden I wan't to change it's attributes the same left, height and marginTop to old default ones without animation, because when I do through animate it appears. I mean becomes display:block. I want to make this hidden and then fideIn.

Comment: Why are you removing these questions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) in a callback which runs once the animation is complete:

```
$('#logo').stop().animate({
    left: 150,
    height: 78,
    marginTop: 45
}, function() {
    $(this).css({
        left: 150, //Change these to whatever they were before the call to animate
        height: 78, 
        marginTop: 45
    }).fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the jQuery [css](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function to set the properties back to their original values.

```
$('#logo').stop().animate({
    left: 150,
    height: 78,
    marginTop: 45
}).hide('slow', function() {
    $(this).css({
      left: 0,
      height: 50,
      marginTop: 10
    }).fadeIn(); 
});
```

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/p7sHz/)